# In eclipse IDE, Is there a way to change font size or colour of comments

Tags: eclipse

When comments are made in eclipse java editor, Is it possible to change the font size and/or colour of the comments without affecting any other part of the document?

Comment: Comments in what? A programming language editor? Which one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes to with some limitations  (depends on Programming language).

For Java:

For Font size and coloring

> Window->Preferences->Appearances->Colors and Fonts->Java

Here you can choose Javadoc but not single line comments

For single comment you can't change the Font size but can change the colors bold etc.

> Window->Preferences->Java->Editor->Syntax Coloring->
>   Choose the type of Comments and change color, bold, italic, underline etc.

Answer (score 0):

You go Window > Preferences > Java > Editor > Syntax Coloring > Comments > Single-line Comment to change the comment color. Generally in Editor path you can do whatever you ask.